# Alternative to foreach loop for Datasnapshot so I can exit loop when condition is met?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently running a forEach loop like bellow:

```
snapshot.forEach((theChild) => 
   let newPostID1 = String(snapshoot.key);
   let newUID = String(child.key);
   //Spill coffee here.
})
```

ForEach loops do not allow you to exit after a condition is met.

**What is an alternative method of looping through my snapshot which allows me to return (exit) after a condition is met?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [val()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val) to get a JavaScript object with the entire set of data at the snapshot.  Then you can iterate its keys using standard JavaScript object property iteration with [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) whenever you want.

```
const val = snapshot.val()
for (const key in val) {
    console.log(`child key: ${key}`)
    console.log(`child value: ${val[key]}`)
    // break whenever you want
}
```